# Scoring Java lambdas with imports

Tags: discussion, policy, code-golf, answers, scoring

In [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/76050/51825), I used a `java.util.List` as a parameter to an anonymous function (lambda) answer. So, my question is,

### Should this import be counted to the byte total?

I know, it feels like the obvious answer should be *YES* - if you don't `import java.util.*`, my example usage won't compile.

However, it's not that simple. I could declare the type ([which we don't score](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4726/51825)) as `BiConsumer<java.util.List<String>, String>` - use the full name instead of importing - and then everything would be fine and dandy. To blur the line further, say an external class has a method that takes a `BiConsumer<List<String>, <String>`. Then, in my test class I could use this lambda without ever referencing the `java.util` package at all!

To clarify, [On scoring imported functions](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8287) refers to scoring a submission of a default method, where this is still scoring a lambda. The issue here is does the import statement need to be counted in the score, as it is possible to compile the lambda without the import but only under very specific conditions.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Java, is it part of Java's standard libraries? Or is it some additional library?

Comment: @Downgoat yes, `java.util` is one of the default classpaths. I don't __think__ this is a dupe as that question concerns scoring when submitting a built in as-is, and this is still a written function.

Comment: `List` is not automatically imported, it requires a specific import statement. This is a duplicate, however, as lambdas are functions.

Comment: @CoolestVeto I may have mis-phrased myself by stating `java.util` as default, as it does require an `import`. Either way, I'm considering this solved as YES. I still don't see this as a dupe but maybe I'm missing something as well.

Answer (score 6):

### Yes, the `import` should be scored.

The argument against is that the code could be compiled without it in certain conditions of surrounding code. However, the lambda, though anonymous, is still a function and not a snippet, and this is what makes it an acceptable answer.

To stand alone, the types of the arguments must be accessible, and as such the `import` should be scored.

More generally, types used as Java lambda parameters must always be imported (and scored as such) or the parameters must be typed to make the lambda a valid stand-alone solution.

Comment: I'm considering the two comments as an effective consensus. I still don't see this as a dupe (I'm not submitting a built-in, just using the features of a List), but I'll leave that to the higher-reps.

Comment: That's pretty brutal against languages like Java and C#, which have very few facilities implicitly imported (not even `ArrayList`/`List`!)

Comment: Hey, I asked this because I primarily like golfing in Java/Kotlin. I may rephrase this question later on and try and present it in light of more recent consensus, and see if I can get a better discussion with points on both sides. (And this question was closed as a dupe of something else for some reason I still don't quite understand?) I understand the issue better now as well. But for now, type your lambdas.

Comment: @Alexander (see above I forgot to tag you) and also, I've seen multiple answers (from higher rep users) even after this that don't do so. Even more reason to bring it up again.

Comment: Yeah, I found this question after searching on whether or not `import Foundation` adds to my byte count. It's pretty much necessary for any non-trivial work in Swift, especially string manipulation. It's a bummer that it's a fixed tax pretty much any complex string/regex manipulation answer in Swift has to pay

Comment: @Alexander If you refer to a type by name, there is no question whether you need to count the import. That's just the "practical" language tax :P

Comment: `Foundation` is a framework, not an individual type and as the name implies... it's pretty fundamental :p

Comment: @Alexander I've used Swift. Swift's `import Foundation` is basically `import stdlib::*` in other languages. And if you want to use a Foundation type unfortunately you have to bring it into the namespace somehow...

Comment: There's a difference. E.g. in `C++` you *can* `import namespace std` and then say `string s = ...`. But it's optional. You could instead just say `std::string s = ...`. Same with Java. In Swift, importing is mandatory, and you can't just say `Foundation.NSSomething`, for example

Comment: @Alexander I don't write the rules, just interpret them. Unfortunately that's the only fair way to score golf: include all code required to make your submission work. And one of the two reasons I don't use Swift is that I don't like its package system (no namespacing, bring in all of a library's types). (The other is that I use Windows.) Anyway, isn't it more Swifty to use non-NS types when possible anyway?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63005/discussion-between-alexander-and-cad97).