# Should "import" statement be included in byte count if I'm not using it directly

Tags: discussion, policy, code-golf

Related: [On scoring imported functions](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8287/on-scoring-imported-functions)

I knew that if I want to use some imported functions, I had to include "import" statement in the byte count. For example, I want to find out the most common character in a string:

```python
from collections import*
lambda x:Counter(x).most_common(1)[1]
```

As the `Counter` function is imported from `collections`, I need to include `from collections import*` into my byte count.

But what should I do if I'm only using some method on inputted object, which you need the "import" to construct the input object?

For example, I want to calculate sum of two fractions:

```python
from fractions import*
f = lambda x,y:x+y
f(Fraction(1, 2), Fraction(1, 3))
```

The function will not cause any error without the import. But you cannot invoke it without the import.

Also, the same thing may happen to third-party libraries too. Another example is, I want to find out all positive number in an array:

```python
import numpy as np
f = lambda x:x[x>0]
f(np.array([1,3,-2,5,-4]))
```

So, how should I score above codes?

1. Is the `fractions` answer valid?
2. Should I include `import fractions` in byte count?
3. Is the `numpy` answer valid?
4. Should I include `import numpy` as in byte count?

Comment: IMO if the question allows taking input as a native or built-in rational type you can probably just assume the function parameters are `Fraction`s, and if they aren't allowed, then even with an `import` it wouldn't be valid. But there are other more nuanced cases where this might apply so I won't answer until I can get a more satisfactory complete answer.

Comment: I'm discussing that the question only says "input as in any reasonable format" or something like it. And I believe if the question require an 1d collection as input (typically Array, LinkedList, Iterable, Iterator, Generator, ...), it will not specially ban `np.array` since most questions are not targeted only Python language.

Comment: I guess it might make sense to include "Python + `numpy`" in the title for fairness of scoring, I suppose. But I'll have to think about this more; this is a very good question.

Comment: @hyper-neutrino Yes, language name should be "Python + `numpy`" for the last case. But language name never contributes to byte count... (as long as you are not using [something like MetaGolfScript](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5076/44718))

Comment: Does [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10085/92901) answer your question? 'If your function is syntactically valid without the `import` (or similar mechanism), then it's not necessary to include the bytes for the `import` in your byte count, even if the `import` is needed to construct objects of the type that your function expects.'

Comment: @Dingus didn’t find out it. I’m going to close this as a dupe. As the two answer under it are both related here.

Answer (score 1):

## Count imports only if the function *definitely* doesn't work without directly importing it

Using the OP's `Fraction` code as an example:

```python
from fractions import*
f = lambda x,y:x+y
f(Fraction(1, 2), Fraction(1, 3))
```

What if I change the example function call to the following? It imports a hypothetical third-party library `frac_consts` which contains definitions of `one_half = Fraction(1,2); one_third = Fraction(1,3)`, and does *not* import `Fraction` directly, but it works totally fine (and adds two fractions as intended):

```python
from frac_consts import*
f = lambda x,y:x+y
f(one_half, one_third)
```

Therefore, `from fractions import*` is not necessary to add two `Fraction`s. This conclusion is consistent with [this answer on a previous discussion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10085/78410); an import that is necessary to construct the arguments *but not required to define the function* may be excluded from the byte count.

Under this reasoning, both answers in the OP's code are valid, and can be scored as `lambda x,y:x+y` and `lambda x:x[x>0]`, respectively.

Comment: Sorry for 1 minutes later... I had closed this question for a dupe of previous one. Feel free to add your thought to answer under that question or vote under that one.